# HTTP/1.1 Server Implementatiion

Tags: c, tcp, httpserver

I have written a HTTP/1.0 server in C. Now I want to be able to serve HTTP/1.1 request as well.
My HTTP/1.0 implementation is as follows:- (Note that I have deliberately removed error handling sections of the code.)

```
while(1) {
        clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &clientName, &clientNameLen);
        pthread_create(&newThread, NULL, serveRequest, (void *) clientSocket);
}

void* serveRequest(void* c){
    char buffer[HTTP_REQUEST_SIZE];
    int clientSocket = (int) c;
    int n = recv(clientSocket, &buffer, HTTP_REQUEST_SIZE, 0);

    struct http_message request;
    int status = http_parser(buffer, &request, HTTP_REQUEST);

    char response[HTTP_RESPONSE_SIZE];
    Response responseStruct = generateResponse(&request, status);
    unsigned int responseLength = responseToString(&responseStruct, response);
    send(clientSocket, response, responseLength*sizeof(char), 0);
    close(clientSocket);
}
```

Now I want to convert this to HTTP/1.1. I searched and found out that, in HTTP/1.1, we dont create new connections every time, rather we receive and send data on already opened connection. How is this implemented practically? How will the above code change?
I am using firefox as my webclient.

Comment: Loops. Keep on receiving requests and sending responses in a loop.

Comment: Do you mean? while(somethingHappens){
recv();
send();
}
close();

Comment: In it most basic and simplified form, yes something like that.

Comment: Your code is already not a proper HTTP/1.0 server since you blindly assume that a request can be read within a single `recv` - which is not guaranteed. Before moving to HTTP/1.1 you first have to implement proper reading of a request header and request body - like specified in the standard. For HTTP/1.1 you on top of this should be able to handle multiple requests after each other in the same connection (HTTP keep-alive) and maybe also before a response got send (HTTP pipelining). You also need to be able to handle chunked request bodies. For all the details please study the actual standards.

Comment: Until you correctly, and completely, handle the results returned from system calls like send(), recv(), there is not much point in further development.  As Steffen says above, you are mishandling TCP:(

Comment: 'int n = recv(clientSocket, &buffer, HTTP_REQUEST_SIZE, 0);'   You cannot ignore n if it is negative.  You cannot ignore n if it is zero.  You cannot ignore n if it is positive.

Comment: (Note that I have deliberately removed error handling sections of the code.)